# PHP get information from array using $_GET suntax

Tags: php, arrays

I have this double array and I need to get the info of it but I have no idea what is the correct syntax to get this working. I have tried a bunch of ways but keep getting either error or no result at all.

Array

```
Array ( [XXX] => Array ( [id] => 23023402 [name] => XXX[profileIconId] => 604 [summonerLevel] => 30 [revisionDate] => 1393143141000 ) )
```

PHP code

```
<?php echo $data**['$_GET['summonerName']']**['summonerLevel']; ?>
```

Issue is in between the ** **. How do I put the variable in there?

Comment: no, im using `$_GET['summonerName']` to get it from the URL. I don't want to print out the summonerName. That is supposed to fill the first `XXX` in my array

Comment: for example if i use `$data['XXX']['summonerLevel']` i'll return 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the quotes

```
$data[$_GET['summonerName']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print out an array like this:

`<?php print_r($data); ?>`

You can replace your stars like this:

`<?php echo $data[$_GET['summonerName']]."-".$data[$_GET['summonerLevel']]; ?>`

Comment: He already used `print_r` on the array, and what's with the hyphen?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is probably a *very* ***very*** bad idea. You are using a request variable to access your `$data` array.

If that array contains the data for different users (summoners), you could potentially leak the information of another.

That being said, you can simply access it using `$data[$_GET['summonerName']]`

Comment: I could use `POST` but since all this information is free as long as someone knows the name i do not see the reason to do it

Comment: Whether or not you use `POST` doesn't really matter, they are both user input. The approach you describe is fine if, `$data` contains nothing at all you don't want exposed. If so, the syntax above will work.

Comment: I was just thrown a bit by the naming `$data` (it's a bit generic). It seems that it could contain "data" for many summoners, in which case you might want to use a non sequential/guessable index.